# Move a file on FTP

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory and the integration runtime installed on an on-premise machine to connect to an FTP and copy files.

All this works, but after the successful copy, the requirement is to move the files on the source FTP to a different folder on that same FTP.

Is this at all possible?
Is it possible to run a script on the on-premise machine using a pipeline and the integration runtime?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by using Azure Data Factory, because the [Azure Data Factory doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) shows the FTP is not supported as sink:

[image]
[image]

So I suggest you to use **FTP client** or **FTP cmd** to move file manually.

**For example:**

I want to move source file `/public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3` to `/public_html/archive/64/SomeMusic.mp3`

then in the **FTP client**:

`rename /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3 /public_html/archive/64/SomeMusic.mp3`

or by **FTP cmd**:

```
RNFR /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3
RNTO /public_html/archive/64/SomeMusic.mp3
```

Comment: Thank you Joseph, I was in fact able to do the first part. The destination sink is a simple file copy (SMB). Once the files have been copied I need to move the files on the source FTP to a different folder on the same FTP. I'm wondering if I can achieve that using an Azure Data Factory pipeline.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that after the Copy Activity runs successfully, then let Data Factory run some scripts to move the files to different folder on the same FTP automatically?

Comment: Exactly! This is possible with some FTP commands, but I don't know how to trigger these

Answer (score 0):

How about use LogicApps?

LogicApps can do the action "copy file (FTP)" and "delete file (FTP)".

Make a LogicApps that is http trigger and trigger it from ADF.